# Phpstorm ftp setting

Tags: php, phpstorm

[image]

the above is the screenshot.

i have set the FTP, the FTP connected ok, when i double clicked the FTP icon. it can't show all the files and directory of the server,i want to change some code of a file which from the remote server, why?

Comment: It would help if you provide a screenshot with your settings and `idea.log` with enabled **deployment** subsystem as described at http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-1202 to JetBrains support.

Answer (score 73):

Click on "Advanced Options..." and toggle "Passive Mode".

Comment: This is a "I'm having same problem" type of answer. This should be a comment, not an answer. Check this [metaSO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question) and [Jon Skeet: Coding Blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx) on how to give a correct answer.

Comment: @Yaroslav I didn't have enough reputation points to comment. You need at least 50: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment)

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, it's perfectly resolved by this answer. Please accept this one!

Comment: This should be marked as Right Answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: This did solve the problem, but can anyone tell me why this worked?

Answer (score 22):

Don't use 'Remote Host' panel.

Try 'Deployment':

Menu **Tools -> Deployment -> Configuration**

There you can define many (S)FTP servers, use mappings, webpath.
You have to fill "Mappings" page which helps phpStorm to figure out where and how exactly local files should be sent to FTP path.

If you will configure it correctly (which is quite simple) you can now enable "Automatic Upload" which activates files uploading after each "Save" option!
You can also manually upload particular files from "Project" pane by RigthClick->Upload

If upload options are disabled (greyed out) try opening configuration again, select server from the list on the left and choose icon 'Set as default' (the 4th icon above left panel - *server with green tick*)

Automatic upload works like a charm in phpStorm!

Comment: I had been off PhpStorm for a while and moved some files around which apparently reset some stuff.  Reconfiguring the mappings worked for me.  I had seen, but ignored, a PhpStorm warning icon about mapping stuff not being set, so I guess I shouldn't be surprised re-setting it worked.

Comment: if deployment options are greyed out, FYI. also you need to make sure you have both paths filled out, even if they are just slashjes \ for deployment path and atleast / for local path

Answer (score 8):

For me, enabling passive ftp didn't fix the grayed out ftp buttons. I did this:

- Open the `Tools > Deployment > Configuration > Mappings`
- Changed a mapping path, saved, then changed it back and saved again.

Then it worked, the buttons **[Upload to]**, **[Download from]** were not grayed out anymore.

Comment: Same here. In WebStorm 9, the "Deployment path on server 'CloudTV'" field was blank under Tools > Deployment > Mappings (apparently it does not default to the root directory). I had to change it to '/' to un-gray the buttons.